# WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from "Clazz" because of underlying class loading error

Tags: jboss, weld, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to run Arquillian tests inside my JBoss EAP server container.
When i run them, i'm getting the following info messages:

```
16:49:48,648 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from package.ChartofaccountDAO because of underlying class loading error
16:49:48,768 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from package.ChartofaccountDAOImpl because of underlying class loading error
```

I think this is the cause because all my CDI injections aren't being processed.
I tried enabling DEBUG in this class to get more information, i've changed standalone.xml to:

```
<root-logger>
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
   <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
       <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
 </root-logger>
```

But i still can only see INFO log records.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution, i had to enable logger in the class and in the console-handler:

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
   <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
   </formatter>
</console-handler>

<logger category="org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: where are this file? what's the file name?

Comment: It's the `standalone.xml` in the `standalone/configuration/` subfolder. The correct logger category for this to work is `org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap` in WildFly 17 btw.